# Azure - Blob Storage

Tags: c#, .net, storage, blob, azure-blob-storage

I've the following scenario.... I am trying to download a file from a site with credentials and store it in the Azure Blob Storage.

For this I've created a app. Using the credentials I am able to access the file and download the file.

For this I've used WebClient.

```
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
CredentialCache cCache = new CredentialCache();
cCache.Add(new Uri(fileURL), "Basic", credentials);

WebClient wClient = new WebClient();
wClient.Credentials = cCache;
wClient.DownloadFile(fileUrl, fileName);
```

Using the above code I was able to download the file onto the machine on the cloud. But I want to store it in the Blob Storage container.

How do I do this.?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebClient.DownloadFile downloads the file to the path specified in the second parameter. In your case, I would like to suggest you to use the DownloadData method, which returns a byte array. Then you can use CloudBlob.UploadByteArray to upload the byte array to blob: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudblob.uploadbytearray.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: What if we need streaming for larger file?

Comment: This link does not work. Do you have the updated link? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN search "c# .net upload file to azure storage"

[azure upload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg651129.aspx)

Can you get you file into a stream?

[BlobUploadStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee772826)

[WebClientToStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I saw this artcile too. But if you see the upload example the Path is hardcoded. In my case, my app runs on Cloud and I do not know where the file is downloaded to!. If i know the path, after downloading it, I can upload it.  I am looking for a solution which will directly write the files to Azure BLOB storage.